# Rails Enum Options with Dynamic Input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, enums

I am developing a class which will require setting an option as follows:

1. Option A
2. Option B
3. Option C
4. Other Option: _________ (fill in the blank)

The options are really long strings. They don't necessarily represent an object state, but answer why a user is submitting a certain form. I have chosen to make them a super basic enum array, storing the key in the database, with an additional column to store the text if the "Other Option" is chosen. So for example, I would store the record like this:

```
# Class
OPTIONS_CONST = ['Option A', 'Option B', 'Option C', 'Other Option']

def get_option_with_other
  return other_option_text if option == OPTIONS_CONST[3]
  OPTIONS_CONST[option]
end

# Database, assuming user chose #4, "Other Option"
my_table.option = 3
my_table.other_option_text = 'This is some big pile of text why I am submitting this.'
```

Is there a more Railsy/conventional way to handle this? I think this is fine for now, but I am fearing it may not scale well, or that there might be a better pattern for handling an enumerated option with user input text among a list of predefined options.

Note: I dont believe `ActiveRecord::Enum` suits my needs here.

Comment: Why do you think that ActiveRecord::Enum doesn't suits your needs?

Comment: @PauloAbreu I think its overkill, and also there is the issue of the dynamic (user) input option. Also, Enum is a "sharp knife": https://bendyworks.com/rails-enum-sharp-knife/. Now that Ive looked at this for a second day though, the issue of the strings being super long can just be alleviated with I18N, dunno why I diddnt think of that aspect yesterday.